# sliding window scenario - taking partitions offline

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is there a way in MS SQL Server 2005 to take a partition / file groups / files offline?

I have a lot of data in certain tables and would like to use the sliding window Scenario:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic24

Instead of keeping all the data in the first partition, I would like to take the partition (or files or file group if possible) offline and make it unavailable for my queries.

Answer (score 3):

The best description of the sliding window scenario I have ever seen is over here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanspo/archive/2009/08/21/inside-of-table-and-index-partitioning-in-microsoft-sql-server.aspx

The article title is "Microsoft SQL Server Inside Out. Inside of Table and Index Partitioning in Microsoft SQL Server".

I do not see the reason to retell this article here. Just go, read and exercise with example by your hands.

And one more very good example is here: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Example_of_Creating_Partitioned_Tables

These two articles should be enough to get your table partitioned even you deal with partitioning at very first time.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can start from here: [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table on SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964122(SQL.90).aspx).

But i would recommend against putting old partitions offline, a much better approach is to have two tables with identical structure, Current and Archive, and use the sliding widnow partitioning to move the old partitions from Current to Archive, see [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160.aspx).

Comment: What about disk I/O in this case? Will anything be written or is this kind of switching a pointer?

Comment: I think what I really want is this: I want the old data to slide out and back it up, then delete the old data after a while.
When it slides out, it should not lock any tables and should not have a large effect on performance.

Comment: Switch partition is a pointer switch. Something is writtent o disk in the table metata, but no dta is moved.